# Add cookie in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have nginx server that serves as proxy for international requests and lives in .com domain.

I have simple proxy configuration, where tradernet.com server proxies all incoming traffic to tradernet.ru server.

What I'm trying to add is language cookie, that will be used by .ru server to serve correct language.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
set $language $cookie_language;

#Setting language cookie
if ($language = "") {
     add_header Set-Cookie "language=en;Domain=.tradernet.com;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000";
}
```

As you can see, I set cookie on domain .com and it takes no effect since server on .ru is waiting for cookie that set to .tradernet.ru domain.

If I try to add cookie with .ru domain, it's not working for some reason - my request is being proxied to .ru server without language cookie at all.

```
add_header Set-Cookie "language=en;Domain=.tradernet.ru;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000";
```

So the question is - how do I add cookie in proxy server that would have another domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace or edit the cookie of your backend server with proxy_cookie_domain
please see
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain

Update:
Maybe I should have explained myself better:

You know already that the second add_header with Domain being set to .ru can't work as browsers won't send that cookie back to tradernet.com.
As to why the first one doesn't work for you I can't say as I don't understand what exactly doesn't work:

- Set-Cookie is not sent to client if there isn't already a language cookie present
- the Set-Cookie part works, but your backend doesn't know how to use it (eg. because it expectes a cookie for .ru but receives a .com cookie)

So what I would do is not to use add_header at all but modify the Cookie your backend already sends, and if it doesn't send a cookie at all implement it there and then simply rewrite the cookie with proxy_domain_cookie. So if your backend already sets a cookie that just misses the language part something like this might help:

```
proxy_cookie_domain tradernet.ru tradernet.com;
proxy_cookie_domain ~^(.+)$ "$1; language=en";
```

Depending on how much you control the logic if you backend, you can also detect the language by adding a header that is sent to to backend-server like

```
proxy_set_header language en;
```